# adb command not found on Mac computer

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to define the android_home path on my mac computer. Below is what i did:

vi ./bash_profile

in the vi editor, I have the following commands:

[image]

My android sdk location is below:

[image]

when I saved the vi editor and ran the adb command. I got an error saying

-bash: adb: command not found

I am now to Mac computer. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Did you source your bash_profile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try to restart the terminal window?

You need either do that or run `source .bash_profile`
for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I restarted the terminal window. That did not work, but doing source .bash_profile worked.!!

Comment: Great! happy to help.